# How to link translated text with original text?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, translation, translate

I have a quite programming challenge here. I want to develop an app in which user upload two books in different languages, and the app will tokenize book into sentenses. These sentenses then will be joined between original and translated text, so when I will read the book in foreign language, and when do not understand the sentense, I'll just click and translated sentense will be shown. The problem is how to link sentenses - I could not just use indexes of tokens, since it is not guarranted that it's translated 1:1. One sentense could be translated into multiple sentenses for instance. Also the translated sentense could be translated in way that particular words do not reflect each other, for example idioms. It doesn't matter, I can omit these, it don't have to be perfect. But it is another pain in term of difficulty of this app. What could be possible solution to this problem that I have in mind is to use diff, which will be modified to not compare string equality, but also the meaning (translation). But maybe some of you will advice something more sophisticated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you know what programming language you will be using? Please choose one.

Comment: Please read and remove the "translate" tag. It is specifically for programming languages, not natural languages.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `ArrayList<String>` of sentences. Same indexes will mean the same sentence. If there are multiple sentences as translation, just put them together.